# jQuery get width of an element that is larger than the viewport

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontally scrolling website and it has a div with `id = "bookWrap"` which is filled with `inline-block` elements so the width is unknown to me but it far extends my viewPort.

While trying to get the width of this element via `$('#bookWrap').width()` jQuery returns my viewport width which is 1680 and not the real width of the element.

How do I go about getting the true width of an element that extends beyond the viewport?

Comment: please give us a http://jsfiddle.net or some source code

Comment: @omnosis Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/szKkT/ , note how when you resize the output window the alert changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should calculate the width:

```
var width = 0;
$('#bookWrap div').each(function(){
   width += $(this).width();
});
alert(width);
```

look here: http://jsfiddle.net/szKkT/4/

Answer (score 2):

Consider this more of a work-around as it seems jQuery `width()` and `outerWidth()` are, for some reason, both cutting off at the viewport width.

```
alert(getTotalWidth("#bookWrap DIV"));

function getTotalWidth(selector) {
    var totalWidth = 0;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
    return totalWidth;
}
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/szKkT/5/)

Comment: This worked for me but I had to do: `$(selector).children().each(..)`

Comment: @ndsc That's because Rory passed in the selector for the children, as opposed to just the outer element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the elements scrollWidth property:

```
var realWidth = document.getElementById('#bookWrap').scrollWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to check which elements are larger than your viewport:

```js
$('*').each(function () {
   var viewportWidth = 768;
   if($(this).outerWidth() > viewportWidth ){
     //prints element in console so you can check what's the element
     console.log($(this)[0]); 
   }
});
```